# why we should not use request dispatcher in dopost?

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I was working with servlet jsp code. I added one record from jsp to database. To show the inserted record I used requestdispacther. But records keep on adding( like infinite loop).
then I replace code with sendredirect and worked fine.
insted of this code:

```
response.sendRedirect("AddNewProductOnRent?action=currentOnRentlist");
```

I was using:

```
RequestDispatcher rs = request.getrequestDispatcher("AddNewProductOnRent?action=currentOnRentlist");
forward(request,response)
```

......but got error

My error solved but I want to know the reason

My servlet code:

```
package com.twd.rent.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.twd.rent.bean.RentBean;
import com.twd.rent.controller.Controller;



/**
    *  Servlet implementation class AddNewProductOnRent
    */
    @WebServlet("/AddNewProductOnRent")
    public class AddNewProductOnRent extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AddNewProductOnRent() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("addnewproductonrent")){

        RequestDispatcher rs =   request.getRequestDispatcher("addnewproductonrent.jsp");
        rs.forward(request, response);

    }else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("currentOnRentlist")) {
        System.out.println("in current on rent list");
        List<RentBean>list=new ArrayList<RentBean>(); 
        list = new Controller().getListOfCurrentOnRent();

        System.out.println(list);
        request.setAttribute("plist",list);
        String forword = "rentlist.jsp";    

        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher(forword);
        rs.forward(request, response);
        }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    String trid = request.getParameter("trid");
    String customertname = request.getParameter("customertname");
    String contact = request.getParameter("contact");
    String date = request.getParameter("date");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");

    RentBean rb = new RentBean();
    rb.setCustomer_name(new String(customertname.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"));
    rb.setContact(contact);
    rb.setDateofissue(date);
    rb.setAddress(new String(address.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(rb.getCustomer_name());

    if(trid.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("In add");

        Controller c = new Controller();
        c.addproductonrent(rb);
        response.sendRedirect("AddNewProductOnRent?action=currentOnRentlist");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("in update");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're forwarding to the same servlet, and the request still has the same method (POST), so it executes the same `doPost()` method again.

You could forward to the view instead, but even then, redirecting is a better choice:

- the browser displays the detail URL rather than the URL used to POST, and can thus bookmark, refresh, or send this URL
- the user can refresh without reposting

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get